# How to display clipboard information in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

What control can display clipboard items and files? I would like the items and files to be able to pasted on selection. And how do I set it so that history of items is shown and the program remembers the items copied on the clipboard.

---

Sorry, I changed my mind to WinForms. I heard that WPF has a very steep learning curve, and since I am already proficient in WinForms, no point in changing to WPF until I have learn much about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How to: Retrieve Data from the Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4.aspx)

> To determine whether the Clipboard
>   contains data in a particular format,
>   use one of the ContainsFormat methods
>   or the GetData method. To retrieve
>   data from the Clipboard, use one of
>   the GetFormat methods or the GetData
>   method.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows clipboard can only contain 1 item, not the history of copied items. So your application has to handle that manually, by monitoring clipboard activity, as explained [here](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3359891/C-Tip-Monitoring-Clipboard-Activity-in-C.htm). Note that in WPF, you can't override the `WndProc` method, so you need to register a hook to process Windows messages using [`HwndSource.AddHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.addhook.aspx).

When you receive a `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` notification, you can access the clipboard data using the `Clipboard` class, and do whatever you need to do with it.

Note that there's a known bug with images in the WPF clipboard, I describe a solution [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/)